# How to manually create a confusion matrix in R?

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I would like to create a confusion matrix for my data in R.

I have a data frame with two variable: predictions and actual.
My predictions column has 356 rows and it contains binary data: predictions=c('0','1','0',1','1','0'). The actual column values are also binary:  actual=c('0','1','0',1','1','0').

How can I create a confusion matrix in R for this data frame? I've tried using table() but did not get expected results, because each column has 356 data points and the table() return only the comparison of 178 data points.

```
predicitons=as.factor(dt$Model)
actual=as.factor(dt$Correct)

t=cbind(predicitons,actual)
dtf=as.data.frame(t)
basic_table <- table(dtf)
print(basic_table)
```

How can I do the confusion matrix correctly?